# Vector access speed, which method is faster?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, vector

I'm curious which method is faster when accessing vectors.

For the sake of simplicity, lets say I have two objects:  `Player` and `Ship`.

There's a vector of player pointers `vector<Player*> players` and each player object contains a vector of ship pointers `vector<Ship*> ships`, and then each ship has several functions that it can call, and so on.

In these situations, is it faster to access these functions directly?  Or to create a temporary object pointer to access everything?

Is it faster to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < players.at(i)->ships.size(); j++)
    {
        players.at(i)->ships.at(j)->update();
        if (
               (players.at(i)->ships.at(j)->get_x() > 0)    &&
               (players.at(i)->ships.at(j)->get_x() < screen_x)    &&
               (players.at(i)->ships.at(j)->get_y() > 0)    &&
               (players.at(i)->ships.at(j)->get_y() < screen_y)
           )
        {
            players.at(i)->visible.push_back(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Or is it faster to create temporary pointers so that the vectors don't need to be continually accessed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++)
{
    Player* play = players.at(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < play->ships.size(); j++)
    {
        Ship* ship = play->ships.at(j);
        ship->update();

        int ship_x = ship->get_x();
        int ship_y = ship->get_y();
        if (
               (ship_x > 0)    &&
               (ship_x < screen_x)    &&
               (ship_y > 0)    &&
               (ship_y < screen_y)
           )
        {
            play->visible.push_back(j);
        }
    }
}
```

I know the second is visually neater, but don't really know if it's necessarily faster.

Thoughts?

Comment: What happened when you profiled both?

Comment: It depends if compiler is able to guarantee that your code doesn't modify the vectors. For example, what happens if `get_x` modifies the players or ships vector? Then the vectors need to be looked up again in the first version. Of course `get_x`, from its name, probably doesn't modify the vectors. But the compiler cannot know that, unless the function code is visible at that time (eg inline function)

Comment: What's faster is `operator[]` instead of `.at()`. Or, using modern C++: `for (Ship& ship : ships) for (Player& play : players)`

Comment: One thing you should really do is replace `players.at(i)` with `players[i]`. The `at()` checks for out of bounds and has a considerable slowdown.

Comment: @vsoftco I don't think so. It's just a check that throws if it fails. Consider there're languages which do bound checking for *every* access.

Comment: @black, checking itself takes some time, and if speed is super super important, you shouldn't use it (basically you have an extra comparison for every access). Imagine you have a ton of elements, and comparing `i<size` for each of them will slow you down a bit, but again, depends how important every nanosecond is for the user.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the operator[] vs the .at().  I didn't know that option was available.  I can see why it'd be faster.
I'll also try out the `for (Ship& ship : ships)`  I'd never seen that either.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that the emphasis on speed is misplaced. I think you should start by writing the code to be more readable:

```
auto is_visible = [=](Ship const &s) { return s.get_x() > 0 && s.get_x() < screen_x 
                                           && s.get_y() > 0 && s.get_y() < screen_y; 
                                     };

for (auto & player : players)
    std::copy_if(ships.begin(), ships.end(), 
                 std::back_inserter(player.visible),
                 is_visible);
```

At least IMO, this is at least as safe as using `at` for indexing, but probably at least as fast as using `[]`, and more readable than either one.

I should probably add one more point: visibility doesn't seem to depend on the player. At least from the way the code's written, all the players will have the same set of visible ships. If that's correct, you probably want to do something more like:

```
std::vector<Ship> visible;

std::copy_if(ships.begin(), ships.end(), 
             std::back_inserter(visible),
             [=](Ship const &s) { return s.get_x() > 0 && s.get_x() < screen_x 
                                      && s.get_y() > 0 && s.get_y() < screen_y; });

for (auto &player : players)
    player.visible = visible;
```

Comment: Readability must be extremely subjective...  But thank you for the coding ideas.
Either way, the checking of the range wasn't the point.  It was merely an example to show the use of vector pointers I was referring to.

Comment: Probably should have bee more clear.  Each player was meant to have their own vector of ships.  So player 1 won't have the same ships as player 2.  Again, the main idea was to demonstrate the methods used, not necessarily accomplish exactly what was shown.  Thanks for the examples though, every different way to accomplish something is something new to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You should check and see which one is faster.

It might be the first or it might be the second. It will definitely be the first if most ships' X coordinate is negative.

However, if the second one looks better to you (it does to me, too), stick with it. Worry about performance when there's an actual performance issue.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was mostly curious if there was a performance degradation from accessing multiple levels of pointers, or if the memory offset was calculated at compile time (basically doing what I did in example 2 behind the scenes.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're at the mercy of your optimizing compiler here. Either one might be faster, depending on how it gets optimized.

- In the first version, it's possible that the compiler will decide to
  pull out the `players.at(i)->ships.at(j)` common subexpression,
  possibly with the `get_x()` or `get_y()` turning it into something
  that looks a lot like your second version.
- In the second version, it's possible that reordering could move the
  `int ship_y = ship->get_y()` into the loop conditional so that it can
  short circuit with `ship_y > 0`.
- In both, it might decide to turn the entire short circuit conditional
  into a sequence of fast bitwise and instructions, eliminating
  branches

But my guess is that you're not going to see much difference either way. Try dumping the assembly code to compare, and of course, profile it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info everyone.  Since there wasn't a clear cut "option A is *definitely* faster than option B", I took your advice and did a bench test.

Here's some code I put together.

Basically, it creates 100 players.  Each player has a vector of 100 ships.  Each ship has a vector of 100 crew.  (Once it ran, it consumed about 500MB of RAM).

I ran the test both unoptimized and optimized (the -O3 flag)

Test 1 was the chain pointers (ie. player->ship->crew->number, etc.)
Test 2 was the same as Test 1, but I replaced all the .at() with operator[].
Test 3 was using temporary pointers to access everything.

I ran each test multiple times and averaged the results.
Here's my results:

Unoptimized:

```
Test 1:  13000
Test 2:  5500
Test 3:  2800
```

Optimized:

```
Test 1:  1050
Test 2:  650
Test 3:  450
```

It shows that optimizing greatly increased speed in all cases.
Either way though, optimized or unoptimized, .at() definitely slows things WAY down.  Using the operator[] was significantly faster.
But in the end, using a temporary pointer was the fastest in all cases.

```
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class People
{
    public:
        vector<int> number;
};

class Ship
{
    public:
        Ship(int f);
        vector<People*> crew;
        int get_x();
        int get_y();

    private:
        int x;
        int y;
};

Ship::Ship(int f)
{
    //Assign some nonsense for testing purposes
    x = f * 50;
    y = f * 75;
}

int Ship::get_x()
{
    return x;
}

int Ship::get_y()
{
    return y;
}

class Player
{
    public:
    vector<Ship*> ships;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<Player*> players;

    int start, end;
    unsigned int i, j, k, l;

    //Create 100 players, each with 100 ships, and each ship with 100 crew.
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Player* play = new Player;
        players.push_back(play);
        for (j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            Ship* new_ship = new Ship(j);
            play->ships.push_back(new_ship);
            for (k = 0; k < 100; k++)
            {
                People* newbie = new People;
                new_ship->crew.push_back(newbie);
                for (l = 0; l < 100; l++)
                {
                    newbie->number.push_back(0);
                }
                newbie->number.clear();
            }
        }
    }    


    //Test 1


    start = clock();

    for (i = 0; i < players.size(); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < players.at(i)->ships.size(); j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < players.at(i)->ships.at(j)->crew.size(); k++)
            {
                for (l = 0; l < 100; l++)
                {
                    //Give each crew some number to hold on to.
                    players.at(i)->ships.at(j)->crew.at(k)->number.push_back(players.at(i)->ships.at(j)->get_x() * players.at(i)->ships.at(j)->get_y() + l);
                }
                //Clear the number list for the next test.
                players.at(i)->ships.at(j)->crew.at(k)->number.clear();
            }
        }
    }
    end = clock();

    cout << "Test 1:   "  << (end - start) << endl;


    //Test 2

    start = clock();

    for (i = 0; i < players.size(); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < players[i]->ships.size(); j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < players[i]->ships[j]->crew.size(); k++)
            {
                for (l = 0; l < 100; l++)
                {
                    players[i]->ships[j]->crew[k]->number.push_back(players[i]->ships[j]->get_x() * players[i]->ships[j]->get_y() + l);
                }
                players[i]->ships[j]->crew[k]->number.clear();
            }
        }
    }
    end = clock();

    cout << "Test 2:   "  << (end - start) << endl;


    //Test 3


    start = clock();

    for (i = 0; i < players.size(); i++)
    {
        Player* temp_play = players.at(i);
        for (j = 0; j < temp_play->ships.size(); j++)
        {
            Ship* temp_ship = temp_play->ships.at(j);
            for (k = 0; k < temp_ship->crew.size(); k++)
            {
                People* temp_crew = temp_ship->crew.at(k);
                for (l = 0; l < 100; l++)
                {
                    temp_crew->number.push_back(temp_ship->get_x() * temp_ship->get_y() + l);
                }
                temp_crew->number.clear();
            }
        }
    }
    end = clock();

    cout << "Test 3:   "  << (end - start) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that your "Test 1" is allocating memory while the subsequent tests are reusing that allocated memory, so you'll see the memory allocation overhead as part of the first test. Also bugs - in "Test 3", your temp_crew is using the wrong index (j instead of k) - and the math is "* l" rather than the "+ l" in the other tests.

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the little bugs.

As for the memory allocation, are you meaning where it uses `.push_back()` on `number`?  I would think since I cleared it, it would be empty again, but maybe not.  Either way, I'll change that.
If you're referring to where I originally create everything, the timer doesn't start until after that's done.
Either way, did some tweaks and recalculated the run times.  Still about the same.

Comment: clear() does not deallocate memory. I tried running the 3 tests twice in sequence, and the Test 1 time dropped by more than half the second time.

Comment: That makes sense.  I updated the code to allocate it in the initial setup.